# Blank array reference in swagger yaml?

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-ui

Iam using swagger documentation for my API.Now really struck with yaml code.
I really want  yaml code for response part from following json code

```
{    
    "status":0,
    "gtasks":[],
    "purchased":[],
    "scnt":0    
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

Blank array is just an state when there is no items for those keys. But if there were any item, the array would be filled with the items. In that case, you still need to provide definition what would be inside those arrays.

Here is schema definition of `YourObjectName` that represents:

```
{    
    "status":0,
    "gtasks":[],
    "purchased":[],
    "scnt":0    
}
```

See comments to fill the array type with either data type or another schema object.

```
definitions:

  YourObjectName:
    type: object
    required:
      - status
    properties:
      status:
        type: integer
        format: int32 # you need
      gtasks:
        type: array
        items: # Need to define item type, could be any data type of object
          type: string
      purchased:
        type: array
        items:
          type: string # For reference to different schema object use $ref: "#/definitions/PurchasedItems"
      scnt:
        type: integer
        format: int32
```

Finally, if you need help, refer to "PetStore" example API spec from http://editor.swagger.io/

Good luck.